# Are these commands considered legal or cheats?

Tags: dota-2

- dota_disable_range_finder
- dota_range_display

Are those safe to use or are they considered to be cheats?

Comment: Offtopic because we cannot answer this, since this is up to the developer to define.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta I disagree. I'm assuming some DotA 2 console commands are considered cheats, while others are not. "Cheats" in this case preventing acquisition of achievements / whatever else. (Though someone with more familiarity with the game may be able to correct me)

Comment: Isn't this game online-only?

Comment: @RavenDreamer What is a cheat and what is not, is not up to us to decide. So unless you can dig up a developers comment on the issue, there is nothing we can do. And a thread on the official Dota 2 forums came up with no developer response so far. And for thus, it is not really advisable to use it. It might get you banned.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta the same could be said about any command. I doubt Valve would be lame enough to ban somebody because they used a legal command (legal = not requiring sv_cheats 1).

Comment: @kotekzot For most things that you can via console, a counterpart in the options exists in Valve Games. Besides bots, but it should be obvious that adding or kicking bots in a offline match is not bannable. However, this is different since this command gives you a clear advantage over other players that do not know about the command. I would classify it as a cheat, but that is the place where opinions come in place and for thus, it is offtopic again since we do also now allow opinion based answers as well as developers intent. 2x offtopic ;)

Comment: What's a cheat and what's not is not for us to decide, that's true, but the game is using Source engine, which flags commands as cheats and those require cheats to be enabled. We *can* tell which commands are like that.

Comment: @3ventic This is not a common case though, it could be a bug that it is there.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta We can't start judging what's a bug and what's not and base our close votes on that.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta On the contrary; if it requires sv_cheats 1, I'd call it a cheat, same as any Source game (see: L4D and TF2).

Answer (score 6):

dota_range_display requires sv_cheats 1. You can use it in custom bot games or other games with cheats enabled, but not in matchmaking. This was not always true, but was changed in a patch a few months ago. Many professional offlaners used this, most notably Admiral Bulldog.

dota_disable_range_finder is not currently considered a cheat and is also used by many professional players, most notably rtz.

Comment: http://www.dota2.com/news/updates/10786/ seems to indicate that dota_range_display requires sv_cheats 1. I could not find anything for dota_disable_range_finder though; maybe you mixed up the commands?

Comment: Yep, reversed. :D

Comment: Told you guys..

Answer (score 1):

It's all good to use these two commands, you can even set them within the game options (or used to be able). Even better, pro's and advanced players have this put off since they know the range by hearth and the circle just adds more stuff going on on the screen.

I can also say with 99% certainty that when you play on the dota servers there are no console command considered cheating. They are just there to debug and set some stuff manually.

Comment: Valve clearly considers it cheating; they removed the ability to have the range indicator displayed in public games and any game with cheats disabled months ago.

Comment: @PWhite Well i can turn it on and off in the options menu. Currently displaying the range indicator since i am trying out some new heroes. If a user is able to use any cheats within the game, with or without use of the console, on there server then it is up to them to fix this. The game is not beta anymore, if a player does find a leak it should obviously be reported and not abused but the matter in question is neither a cheat nor can it be abused.

Comment: The circle radius around your hero cannot be enabled in public games. If you can do so congratulations; please report it.

Answer (score 0):

In general any command in the console that requires `sv_cheats 1` to work, is considered a cheat. Modifying the game files is considered a cheat.

Other than that you can bind macros to any commands, or use any commands that you wish. VAC only checks for modified files or other apps running in the background that affect the game and/or Steam, and sv_cheats 1 is simply not allowed on servers.